# is it ok to use multiple audio tags

Tags: html, audio, mpeg

when I use the basic setup:

```
<audio>                                                   
  <source id   = 'for_mp3'        
          src  = ''           <!-- src is set on demand -->                            
          type = 'audio/mpeg'                         
  >                                                 
  <source id   = 'for_wav'         
          src  = ''                                    
          type = 'audio/wav'                          
  >                                                     
  <span>    
    no audio ha                                                      
  </span>                                                       
</audio>
```

... firebug in FF21 says:

> Specified "type" attribute of "audio/mpeg" is not supported. Load of media resource failed.
>   warning.

So is it ok to use both audio tags (and ignore the warning)?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: Zenith, yes I have seen examples of the multi-audio usage, but the warning in firebug is bothering me ... it also seems that if I comment out the mp3 audio tag that there is an improvement in page-loading.

Comment: Did you try specifying the codecs in your code like the article mentioned?

Comment: I have not specified codec ... because A) I have seen forum posts where people's codec declarations were causing  problems, B) because there are trillions of codes, and trying to manage that would seem like an infinite challenge with high-probability for pitfalls.

Comment: You don't actually have that random HTML comment in the middle of your source tag like that in the live page, do you? That's certainly not valid HTML.

Comment: animuson ... no I put it there for this post

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, warnings can generally be ignored since they usually do not interfere with the running of the program. It is errors you have to watch out for.

Although, the warning you are receiving does bother me since it explicitly says "load of media resource failed" and if the loading failed, there will be no audio.

Is there a particular reason you are trying to use both of the tags together? If there is not, I would just go with using one since using them both seems to be causing a problem. Both tags shouldn't be "needed" so if you are still getting the same error, try using one at a time and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: ... using both audio tags to cast a wider net for various browsers ... for instance, .wav is needed for FF (currently), but .mp3 is needed for IE9+ ... As Zenith noted above via his [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) "Multiple source files can be specified using the <source> element in order to provide video or audio encoded in different formats for different browsers."

Comment: ok I see what you mean. you're code should work. have you tried ignoring the warning and just testing to see what happens? I'm sure you have thought of doing that already, but if not I would give it a shot just to see if the warning seems to have any real merit.

Comment: animuson has a good point. That commment could be what is throwing off your HTML. wish i would have thought of that sooner. I had the same issue with a comment in some HTML I working on last week. My page got all kinds of weird and it took me forever to think about removing the comment. When I did, it fixed the problem. Try moving or removing the comment. @animuson, nice catch there!

Comment: Jason, the audio plays ... the wav plays, that is. So, yes, it is ignorable, but ...

Comment: Jason9024 ... I discovered today that every time I get that warning, that jquery mobile's pageinit event is fired. .......... that warning is fired 4 times, thus I end up with 4 pageinits, and they all come in about .5 second intervals.

Comment: actually pagebeforecreate/pagecreate/pageinit etc are all fired after every <audio>-related warning ... ... even if I bind to those page events using **.one(...)** (_instead of .on(...)_)